# Narrow relationship results in octobercms form by current backend user

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have these three models:

> 1. Teacher: belongs_to: 'user' => 'Backend\Models\User',
>      has_many: 'classes' => 'Acme\School\Models\Class'
> 2. Classes: belongs_to: 'teacher' => 'Acme\People\Models\Teacher',
> 3. Schedule: belongs_to: 'class' => 'Acme\School\Models\Class'

I'm trying to build a form for model Schedule where a teacher can select only from his classes in order to complete his schedule. For the moment I have this in schedule/fields.yaml:

```
    fields:
      class:
        label: Class
        nameFrom: full_name
        span: auto
        required: 1
        type: relation
```

I tried adding scope to the field definition but in Model\Classes I don't seem to have access to Request, User or Auth.

- please note that Class is not the real model name, nor classes the relationship's name.
- if the title of my question is not good enough please recommend me another one.
- if the solution is an easy and obvious one I think I'll shoot myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar and solved it with an scope, in the scope you have access to the Backend User with BackendAuth::getUser()

I have this scope:

```
public function scopeHasAccess($query)
{
    if (BackendAuth::getUser()->is_superuser) {
        return;
    }

    $query->whereHas('clients', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', BackendAuth::getUser()->id);
    });
}
```

But I'm doing the scope only in the backend relation implementing the RelationController Behaviour

https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#introduction

Comment: I didn't knew about BackendAuth. It solves my problem. Thank you!